# ¿Como puedo hacer para que el label de mi input no se sobre escriba en el texto que ingresa mi usuario después de cambiar de casilla?

Tags: html, css, css-transform

De ante mano muchas gracias!

Sucede que tengo un `input` que tienen un `label` y lo edito mediante `CSS` para que el `label` se ubique dentro del `input` pero cuando le dan click en el `input`, el `label` se ubica al borde superior del `input`. Y cuando pasan a la siguiente casilla ese `label` regresa automáticamente al centro del `input` y se sobré escribe en el texto que ingresa mi usuario.

Esto es un ejemplo que encontré y hasta ahora estoy viendo `CSS` y no me queda muy claro, cómo podré corregir esto?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
}

.input-container {
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
}

.labelUsuario {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 14px;
  transition: all .25;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #010101;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-input {
  padding: .8rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #C8C5C5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  transform: all .3s;
  color: #010101;
  background-color: #F1EFF0;
}

labelUsuario::before {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #010101;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #C8C5C5;
}

.text-input:focus+.labelUsuario,
.filled {
  top: -10px;
  color: #010101;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.text-input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.text-input:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="username" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Su Nombre o Razón..." />
    <asp:Label class="labelUsuario" for="username" Text="Ingrese Razón Social o Nombre" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="datosContacto" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Datos..." />
    <asp:Label class="labelUsuario" for="datosContacto" Text="Datos de Contacto" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te referis a que el label se mueve del centro? porque copie todo y en ningun momento se mueve. Acordate de importar el archivo normalize.css (esta en la web) que corrige varios errores inesperados.

Comment: Cuando le doy click el label se cambia de posición a la parte superior izquierda del input box y cuando el usuario escribe y pasa al siguiente input box el label regresa a su primera posición y queda sobre el texto que el usuario escribió, te adjunto una  imagen para que lo puedas ver!

Comment: lo unico que se me ocurre es que no tengas el normalize.css, me anda perfecto a mi, te paso el html

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu apoyo! ya publique una respuesta y solo fue necesario editar un fragmento del css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solucion que encontre y que me funcionó para hacer que quedara el `label` fijo en la parte superior del campo de texto cuando se ingresa algún dato, para que no se sobre escriba el `label` en el texto ingresado, solamente fue necesario editar el `CSS` en un fragmento del primero que mostré, lo dejo por si alguien lo necesita.

```
.text-input:focus + .labelUsuario, .filled, .text-input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .labelUsuario {
top: -10px;
color: #010101;
background-color: white;
font-size: 1em;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css"> <!-- importando normalize -->
    <script defer src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<form>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="username" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Su Nombre o Razón..." />
    <asp:Label class="labelUsuario" for="username" Text="Ingrese Razón Social o Nombre" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="datosContacto" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Datos..." />
    <asp:Label class="labelUsuario" for="datosContacto" Text="Datos de Contacto" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```